# view.getTag(key) returns null in android

Tags: android, gridview, view

I've used below code in my app. View.getTag returns null value in outside of getView method.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        mHolder = new GridViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.grid_view_item, parent, false);
        mHolder.overflowButton.setOnClickListener(overflowClickListener);
        mHolder.titleText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridViewTitleText);
        convertView.setTag(mHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        mHolder = (GridViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    titleText = "tagsvalues";
    convertView.setTag("titleText", titleText);
    mHolder.titleText.setText(titleText);
    return convertView;
}

/**
 * Click listener for overflow button.
 */
private OnClickListener overflowClickListener = new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(v.getTag("titleText") == null)
            Log.e("mName", "Null value returns by above getTag");
    }
};
```

Please check and guide me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i slightly improved formatting for you. anyway does the last semicolon (`;`) really need to be there? it does not alter the result but i at least think it's wrong placed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the click listener on `mHolder.overflowButton`. This overflowButton doesn't have any tags. Notice that you're setting the tag on `convertView.setTag("titleText", titleText);` and not the `overflowButton`.

Fix: `mHolder.overflowButton.setTag("titleText", titleText);`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This could be a simple issue for others but for me it's big one :) since I'm not properly aware of tag's importance. Thanks once again.